# Finding Minimum Weight Subgraph Spanning Tree

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, trees, combinatorial-geometry

Suppose we have a graph $G = (V, E, w:e\in E \to x \in \{0,1\})$. That is, a set of vertices, a set of edges and a weight function that assigns edges weights of 0 or 1.

Suppose we also have a subset of vertices $S \subset V$ and that we want to find a minimum-weight tree that spans the vertices in $S$. Since the vertices in $S$ might not be directly connected, we are allowed to use vertices in $V$ that may not be in $S$ to build our minimum-weight tree.

Is there an algorithm similar to Prim's or Kruskal's that we can use to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a generalization of minimum Steiner tree that is an NP-hard problem and in general, there is no polynomial algorithm to solve it. More explanation can be found at [Generalization of minimum Steiner tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem#Generalization_of_minimum_Steiner_tree)